# Norms Equivalence over $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any norm on $\mathbb R^n$.

Prove that a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ is Cauchy under the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm if and only if the sequance is Cauchy under the $\|\cdot\|$.

Prove that a set in $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded under $\|\cdot\|_2$ if and only if the sequence is bounded under the $\|\cdot\|$

Is there a general way for these type of questions or are they different for each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimensional real (or complex) vector space all norms are equivalent. That means (following your notation) there are $c,d\in \mathbb R$ such that 
$$c||x||\leq ||x||_2\leq d||x||$$

Now the properties you want to show follows from this inequality.

Comment: So I need to show c=d for each case?

Comment: no, not at all. In fact $c=d$ will not be true.

Comment: Oh.. got it. i do not need to show they are equal to show they are bounded . and i do not need to prove $\mathbb R^n$ is a finite dimension. it is a known property of $\mathbb R^n$ correct?

Comment: yes you don't need them to be equal. And $\mathbb R^n$ is clearly finite dimensional; it is $n$ dimensional to be precise. Just by the definition of dimension.

Comment: this page might give you a bit more insight https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)